# erlang: UNIX domain socket support?

Tags: linux, sockets, erlang, unix-socket

Is there a way to access UNIX domain sockets (e.g. /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket ) directly from Erlang **without** resorting to a third-party driver?

Comment: There is a /lib/kernel/examples/uds_dist in the erlang source distribution, but it uses a driver. Does that count third party ? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Erlang/OTP comes with drivers for tcp and udp sockets only. So...

No.

### Third part drivers

- unixdom_drv in http://jungerl.sourceforge.net/
- uds_dist in the source tree's driver examples
- procket at https://github.com/msantos/procket

Comment: thats so very very sad

Answer (score 14):

In Erlang/OTP 19.0, UNIX Sockets are now available, [as stated in the readme](http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_19.0.readme):

> OTP-13572    Application(s): erts, kernel
>
> Related Id(s): PR-612
>
> *** HIGHLIGHT ***
>
> Experimental support for Unix Domain Sockets has been
>                  implemented. Read the sources if you want to try it
>                  out. Example: gen_udp:open(0,
>                  [{ifaddr,{local,"/tmp/socket"}}]). Documentation will
>                  be written after user feedback on the experimental API.

**Example:**

lsock.erl:

```
-module(lsock).
-export([watcher/1, test/0]).

watcher(Parent) -> 
  {ok, Sockin} = gen_udp:open(0, [{ifaddr, {local, "/tmp/testsockin"}}]),
  io:format("watcher ok? ~w ~w~n", [ok, Sockin]),
  Parent ! start,
  receive
    Msg -> io:format("watcher got: ~p ~n", [Msg]) end.

test() ->
  file:delete("/tmp/testsockin"),
  file:delete("/tmp/testsockout"),
  _ = spawn(lsock, watcher, [self()]),
  {ok, Sockout} = gen_udp:open(0, [{ifaddr, {local, "/tmp/testsockout"}}]),
  io:format("parent ok? ~w ~w~n", [ok, Sockout]),
  receive start ->
    gen_udp:send(Sockout, {local, "/tmp/testsockin"}, 0, "hi") end.
```

And the following demonstrates its results:

```
$ erlc lsock.erl 
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.1] [source-ca40008] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0.1  (abort with ^G)
1> lsock:test().
<0.58.0>
parent ok? ok #Port<0.455>
watcher ok? ok #Port<0.456>
watcher got: {udp,#Port<0.456>,{local,<<"/tmp/testsockout">>},0,"hi"} 
ok
2>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`nanomsg` library](http://nanomsg.org) supports Unix domain sockets, and the [`enm` driver](https://github.com/basho/enm) provides an Erlang language binding for `nanomsg`.

For example, to open the response side of a request/response protocol and bind to a Unix domain socket address:

```
Url = "ipc:///path/to/socket/file",
{ok,Rep} = enm:rep([{bind,Url}]),
```

Here, `Rep` is a `nanomsg` socket. It supports `send` and `recv` as well as all the usual Erlang `{active, true | false | N}` modes, etc. that regular Erlang TCP/SCTP/UDP sockets provide. For more details consult the [`enm` github README](https://github.com/basho/enm/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hackney](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney) if you want to recieve http response as hackney provides support to UNIX socket .
hackney:get<<"http+unix://path_to_ sock_file.sock">>