# Same Machine Erlang communication

Tags: asynchronous, erlang, multithreading, ipc, portability

I need an answer to the following question to help understand what approach I should be taking to interface with Erlang. AFAIK Erlang on a SMP UNIX box uses the multi-process approach. In this case it should do same machine IPC.

1. Does Erlang use UNIX domain sockets for UNIX ?
2. Does it use named-pipes for windows ?
3. If it does not implement both constructs above -- i.e., no named-pipes for windows; it must have to fallback to sockets, on windows.
4. How are the above mentioned principles implemented, do they use message oriented, single-thread per channel, asynchronous constructs or is it something else ?
5. If my line of reasoning above is incorrect, does it use a master-child tree and all other processes communicate -- indirectly -- through the master ?

-- edit 1 --

[Link](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ei.html) to the erlang binary format documentation.

The universal concensus is that Unix Domain Sockets outperform [TCP/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257433/postgresql-unix-domain-sockets-vs-tcp-sockets). I think I will try to extend Erlang to use the better primitives provided. I also strongly suspect that epol and windows IOPC is not used in the TCP/IP event loop -- I will post back once I have audited the code.

Another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478831/erlang-unix-domain-socket-support) that asserts that Erlang indeed, does not support anything other than TCP and UDP.

There are two Erlang libraries for communication [`Erlang node -> c_node`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_connect.html) and [`c_node -> Erlang_node`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ei_connect.html)

The Erlang [module for sockets](http://www3.erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.8.1/pdf/sockets-1.0.5.pdf) allows Unix Dom Sockets to be opened under UNIX.

Comment: relevant SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478831/erlang-unix-domain-socket-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R1. It uses TCP/IP (in fact, there isn't any "standard" support for UNIX domain sockets)

R2. I am pretty sure it is still TCP/IP sockets

R3. see R2

R4. There is a binary exchange format proper to Erlang and it is message based. Exchanges can either be sync (RPC-like) or async.

R5. No master.

---

As bonus (to help you save time):  don't forget to use a registered name (-sname or -name) in order to use inter-node communications (either RPC or whatever).

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the question, but it's hard to believe Erlang schedulers communicate via TCP/IP.

Comment: @zed, yes it is hard to believe. I've seen many sub-optimal IPC implementations in my review of open source stuff. The BSD TCP/IP and select() is pretty much the standard a lot of people program against. I would appreciate a link to a source file, or reference manual about the schedulers, that is if you find any.

Comment: Guys - maybe I've read the question with tinted glasses: I was assuming IPC **between** nodes (in the Erlang sense) because if we are talking about **intra-node IPC**, then of course I am pretty certain it is **not** over TCP/IP.

Comment: Erlang does support a module for sockets, which does allow [`AF_UNIX`][1] sockets to be opened (only for unix ofcourse).  this makes it possible for the scheduler to pick AF_UNIX on UNIX and default to TCP/IP on windows.

[1]: http://www3.erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.8.1/pdf/sockets-1.0.5.pdf

Comment: p.s. The schedular is probably written in C. I am assuming because the scheduler is being discussed that it is running in a seperate scheduler master process ? Shouldn't each node have its own scheduler ? And why do schedulers talk to each other, are we talking about the same machine transparent message passing that goes on between nodes on the same machine?

Comment: Each node does have its own scheduler. I do not know why we are discussing schedulers here either.

Comment: [Explains][1] the SMP model used by Erlang, it uses a single-process multi-thread model. Local IPC from the perspective of the scheduler is therefore a non-issue.

[1]: http://www.erlang.org/euc/08/euc_smp.pdf

Answer (score 14):

As a comment to your original question and to some of the comments:

- I am **VERY** sure, in fact I **KNOW**, that internally within a node the Erlang VM does not use sockets or pipes for communication between (Erlang) processes. That would be ludicrous and completely go against the basic Erlang principles of light-weight inter- (Erlang) process communication.
- Between Erlang nodes the Erlang VM uses TCP/IP. The semantics and behaviour as seen from Erlang are the same as for intra-node communication, in most respects it is completely transparent on which nodes the processes involved lie.
- SMPs don't change these basics, irrespective of how many cores and schedulers are used, and irrespective of how many schedulers are run per core.

Comment: More detail about how Erlang's within node message passing system works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391274/how-does-erlang-pass-messages-between-processes-on-the-same-node/3397945#3397945