# How can I send messages to an existing Unix socket from Erlang?

Tags: erlang, unix-socket

I see that [gen_udp](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_udp.html) has support for Unix sockets, and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38286954/4376) shows creating an using one in Erlang.

I want to send messages to an existing Unix socket (to control [mpv](https://mpv.io/) via its JSON IPC interface). I see there was [a self-answered question on the Erlang mailing list](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2018-November/096626.html) about this, but the answer doesn't make sense to me, as `Sock2` is used without previous assignment.

I see in the `gen_udp` docs this option:

```
{fd, integer() >= 0}

  If a socket has somehow been opened without using gen_udp,
  use this option to pass the file descriptor for it.
```

But when I try to open the socket as a file with `file:open/2`, I get `{error,eopnotsupp}`.

**How can I send messages to an existing Unix socket?**

Comment: The mailing list example is working if you get `Sock2` like this: `{ok, Sock2} = gen_udp:open(0, [local]).`

Answer (score 0):

## Answer for my case

This will not be a canonical and thorough answer, because I'm not super familiar with sockets. However, I emailed Joe from the mailing list link above, and he said:

> As far as I understand, the unix socket type to erlang module mapping
>   is as follows:
>
> ```
> SOCK_STREAM -> gen_tcp
> SOCK_DGRAM -> gen_udp
> SOCK_SEQPACKET -> gen_sctp
> ```

He suggested using `gen_tcp:connect` in my case, and it worked! Apparently, mpv created a `SOCK_STREAM` socket.

So, having started `mpv` like:

```
mpv /Users/me/playlist.m3u --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpv.sock --idle yes --no-audio-display
```

... so that it expects commands on the socket `/tmp/mpv.sock`, I could send it a "play a different playlist" command like this in `erl`:

```
{ok, Port} = gen_tcp:connect({local, "/tmp/mpv.sock"}, 0, [local]).
Msg = "{ \"command\": [\"loadlist\", \"/Users/me/playlist2.m3u\", \"replace\"] }\n".
gen_tcp:send(Port, Msg).
```